# Is there another tool out there for building oracle reports other then oracle reports builder?

Tags: oracle, reporting, report, oraclereports

I cant stand oracle reports builder. Its constantly crashing and sucking in general. Copying and pasting stuff only sometimes works. Elements visualy look selected after you unselect them. AARRRRRRRRGGHHHHHHHHHHHH!!! I need another tool. Are their any alternatives for designing the report jsps?

Comment: I'd take the 'Oracle' aspect out of the whole thing. JasperReports seems to be the reporting tool of choice at the moment.

Comment: I share your pain :) ... btw, with the "selected" problem, I find if you scroll the window back and forth, the little boxes disappear.

Comment: Just getting the data into a report is not really the issue. I was just having some layout formatting troubles yesterday and then once again reports builder crashed on me after not saving for a couple hours so I had to get on SO and complain. Im pretty submissive with those handing down the design reqs as long as they give me the hours to do it. Im doing a bunch of reports for a new module to an existing application so i need to conform to the existing reporting tool/template. I have taken the oracle university reports training but dont work with oracle that often so im kind of relearning.

Comment: I just wish oracle would build a better tool. Or atleast one that didnt crash as often. I remember even in the training. The guy telling us to save constantly.

Comment: Its a shame this question got closed. You would think that there might be a different tool created to develop these reports since they end up as JSPs. The oracle report builder tool can definitely be tough to work with.

Comment: In general, Oracle is an overpriced piece of dung. Their triggers are worthless for business logic and development in Oracle like you mention - it blows. Oracle is only interested in sucking the money out of corporations and nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother switching tools, you'll probably only be disappointed.  I've used many reporting tools and all of them have significant issues.  No matter which tool you use you'll probably end up fighting it and gradually move more and more of your logic into the database.  The more SQL tricks you learn the less you'll have to rely on poorly designed reporting tools.

Comment: sooooo... i hated to unselect this as the answer but i thought it would be fun to leave this question open. Just in case anyone stumbled upon it with some mind blowing alternative.

Comment: yeah the 11g one is not so bad... and it lets you recover your work if it crashes on you wich is a HUGE improvement

Comment: I've used Oracle for over ten years and it hasn't improved at all.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread but here my take on it. For experienced developers (I should point out that I am one), Oracle Reports is unbelievably productive tool. For new developers, it can be baffling and frustrating. I have been in the "market" for an Oracle Reports alternative for some time now and have yet to find a tool that can do what Oracle Reports can do for me.  The tools I have looked at:

- Oracle BI Publisher: Officially, this is the successor to Oracle Reports. One day it will be as good as Oracle Reports...right now it primarily uses MS Word as the report designer. Its not fun to to wrestle with Word (nested) tables (which replaces frames). I would prefer Reports Frames any day.
- Pentaho: I looked at this with minor interest, it's commercial open source and I thought did a pretty good job. Not sure how it scales and like all open source projects, is at the mercy of an active community.
- MicroStrategy: This is again a very seasoned product. BI is their bread and butter and so I would expect that its pretty good. I had a vendor do a POC and they replicated one of my most complex "Form" type reports (a business document, bill-of-lading). The price however it at enterprise level (read: very pricy). Although for departmental deployments they have a 'free' version.
- Microsoft Reporting: This one has good promise but it is sold primarily with MS SQL Server and I being an Oracle-guy has felt internal resistance to this tool. One of these days I will overcome it when the Reports Builder has crashed one too many times.

There are scores of others like JasperReports, Actuate, Business Objects (Crystal), Information Builders etc.

Answer (score 3):

Microstrategy or Business Objects. 
You may develop a custom software as erbsock has told, like a lightweight BO, create views from the selected fields by users, name them as reports and schedule a job to send them as a CSV file or in a jsp file , whatever the view part is. 
Also in Oracle Reports Builder, if you are not mentioning the old 6i interfaced tool, try to build one big query and try to build the XML using the publisher. I am outdated about it , but remember something like that. 
I will ask about it to an expert friend of mine.

Best Regards,

Kayhan YÜKSEL

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL and understand your data model and plug it into an excel spreadsheet using ODBC?

Comment: That looks like a neat option for future tasks. Im not sure if i can meet my time and style reqs by switching. I was pretty much just coming to SO to complain, but I am very interested in reporting alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

After using the tool for a year, we are familiar than past. We still have challenges that implementations worked fine in TOAD, but the code does not work in Oracle Report.
After crashing several time, we have done  <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> before run the project. Plus, we save every hours as a previous draft.
It help us to lost our works but we need more space for them.

Comment: Saving all the time definitely helps. There is a newer version of reports builder out now. I had been using the one from the Oracle developer sweet. I had trouble configuring the new reports builder on my current development VM(64bit windows 7) because of all the fusion midleware stuff you need, so i still use the older tool on an XP VM thats dedicated to reports. I would assume that the newer tool has less problems, but I havnt tried it yet